# Booking sheet with list of room number by the current month in year

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is rooms table for room information where tag rooms number and rooms details Table [image: Rooms Table].
This is booking table for booking information where tag customer id from customer table,hotel id from hotel list table,check-in-date,check-out-date,booked via etc table [image: Booking Table].
This is room book table for booked rooms tag with booking id,room id,hotel id etc table [image: Room Book Table].

Actually i solved half code table [image: Rooms booked overview].
my code is.

```
$date = $_GET['sdate'];
$parts = explode('-', $date);
$likedata = $parts[0] . '-' . $parts[1];
$end = $parts[0] . '-' . $parts[1] . '-' . date('t', strtotime($date)); 
$monthNum = $parts[1];
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
$data['monthname'] = $dateObj->format('F');

$data['sdate'] = $date;
$data['edate'] = $end;
$data['sssdate'] = $date;
$data['esdate'] = $end;
$data['rooms'] = $this->user_model->get_room([
'hotel_id' => $this->session->userdata('hotel_id')]);
$data['room_book'] = $this->user_model->get_room_book([
'hotel_id' => $this->session->userdata('hotel_id'), 
'book_from like' => $likedata . '%']);
$this->load->view('overview2_view', $data);
```

i want like this table [image: like this]. please help thanks to advance.

Comment: Can you please paste array $data['room_book'] structure ?

Comment: Model structure?

Comment: No, the array structure. I think you have to add another level on you $data['room_book'] array to test with a boolean from the template if the room is actually booked for this date.